# Sequence of projectors that does not converge

Tags: hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, compact-operators, adjoint-operators, separable-spaces

Let $\big(H,\langle.,.\rangle \big)$ be a **separable** Hilbert space, with an *orthonormal basis* $\{u_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, and set $V_N = <u_0, \dots, u_N >$ (the set of all the linear combinations generated by $\{u_n\}_{n=1}^{N}$). 
Let $P_N:X \rightarrow V_N$ be the *projector* over $V_N$.

How can be proved that $P_N$ does NOT converge (as $N \rightarrow \infty$) in the operator norm?

I have proved that $P_N$ is linear and bounded for every $N$. But I still miss the more important part.
Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Write down what $P_{N+1}-P_N$ does; show it has norm $1$.

Comment: Thank you, @David C. Ullrich . It was trivial.
$$
   P_{N+1}-P_N = P_{<u_{N+1}>} \in \mathcal{B}(H,H), \quad \Vert (P_{N+1}-P_N) (u_{N+1}) \Vert = \Vert u_{N+1} \Vert
$$